# How do I get involved in Ubuntu?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I recently graduated from a H.Dip course in Software Development. I really want to get involved in some Ubuntu desktop development projects. I'm most competent in Java and also have MySQL knowledge. I also have a decent competency in web technologies such as HTML, CSS and Javascript. It seems from what I have read so far that there's myriad different ways and languages to program for Ubuntu and I'm just wondering considering my core skills what ye might recommend would be the best way to put the first foot forward?

Comment: There are lots of ways to contribute to Ubuntu and they don't all have to be technical take a look at [ContributeToUbuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ContributeToUbuntu) on the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/).  If you are looking to use your skills as a programmer I know the [Bug Squad](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BugSquad) are always looking for help. You are also contributing to Ubuntu by answering support questions on this site, [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) or [Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+questions)

Answer (score 2):

With the skills you listed you should look at getting involved with the [Creating Evernote on Ubuntu for smartphones](http://insights.ubuntu.com/news/creating-evernote-on-ubuntu-for-smartphones/) project

Answer (score 1):

One of the best ways to check out how you can best use your skills is to take a look at http://community.ubuntu.com/. If you're into programming, joining the development team may be your best bet.

According to the [Ubuntu Community](http://community.ubuntu.com) page, developers "write and package new software or fix bugs in existing software. Your technical skills can make a real difference". Check out http://community.ubuntu.com/contribute/developers/ for more detailed information on what exactly you can do, but of course nothing stops you from engaging in other aspects of the community such as documentation, design, translations, quality, support and documentation.